# What are the meanings for these symbols?

Tags: occultism, pagan

I wasn't sure what the right place was to ask this question but since it pertains to identifying presumably occult or pagan symbols this seemed like the right stackexchange.
[image]
I saw these symbols on a few pieces of clothing and have been trying to find their meaning for days. There are three symbols in total, five if you want to count the variations of two of them as separate symbols. They each contain a crescent moon and some parts that are reminiscent of demonic sigils but I can't pin down these exact symbols.

I found a different version of the garment itself that contains Icelandic symbols and the actual Nábrókarstafur but nothing on this set of symbols.

What is the origin and meaning of the five symbols presented on **this garment specifically**?

Answer (score 2):

These are mostly not pagan symbols in origin.

[image]

The crescent moon with crosses derives from one of the oldest symbols for orthodox  Christianity and was taken over by early Islam, replacing the crosses with a star.

[image]
The crescent moons (1 with semicircle, 1 with lines) are likely a simplified rendering from ancient Hindu moon mandala patterns.

[image]

This is the only symbol that arguably has what Christians would consider pagan origins. It is an alternative rendering of the Celtic triple moon symbol.

Comment: The question is looking for the origin and meaning of the specific five symbols displayed in the included image, not vaguely related symbols. The only one of those you provided that is close is the triple moon and even it isn't near close enough.

Answer (score 2):

**What are the meanings for these symbols?**

They are simply modern punk prints for selling purposes!

[image: Punk Style Moon Print]

[image: Punk Style Moon Print]

[image: Punk Style Moon Print]

For myself, they seem to be a **Gothic Style Print**, but they are listed as [**Punk Style Moon Print**](https://www.beautifulhalo.com/punk-style-moon-print-long-sleeve-open-front-hooded-coat-p-316113.html). Thus they represent simply the different phases of the moon! Nothing more, nothing less.